# Пакеты не доходят до TCP сервера

Tags: сервер, golang, tcp, клиент, telnet

Поднял простенький TCP сервер на Go. Подключился к нему через телефон по telnet через WiFi через местный роутер в локальной сети. Потом повозился немного с прокси на squid и сервер перестал отвечать на запросы. Причем если поднять сервер на другой машине, то с первой к ней подключаться получается. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: проблема в прокси. посмотрите какие типы пакетов, портов и адресов рвзрешены на вашем прокси

Comment: Удалил все правила iptables, заработало, спасибо.

Comment: всегда пожалуйста. вы можете поблагодарить в виде принятного ответа, если ответ решил вашу проблему.

Answer (score 1):

проблема в прокси-сервере. Посмотрите какие типы пакетов, портов и адресов разрешены на вашем прокси и откройте доступ для tcp и нужного порта.

Посмотреть можно командой `iptables-save`